# valgrind reporting invalid read with std::string

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, valgrind

I'm working on code that runs on a raspberry pi 3. And got the following error on my logging classes.

```
==1297== Invalid read of size 8
==1297==    at 0x4865D1C: ??? (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so)
==1297==  Address 0x4c8d45c is 100 bytes inside a block of size 107 alloc'd
==1297==    at 0x4847DA4: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:328)
==1297==    by 0x49C3D9B: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::reserve(unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6.0.22)
==1297==    by 0x4AE65: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > std::operator+<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (basic_string.tcc:1155)
==1297==    by 0xF82B5: Log::Book::addField(std::unique_ptr<Log::Entry, std::default_delete<Log::Entry> >&, unsigned int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (LogBook.cpp:149)
==1297==    by 0xF7CCB: Log::Book::record(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int, unsigned int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<1ll, 1000000000ll> > >) (LogBook.cpp:87)
```

GCC version: gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Raspbian 6.3.0-18+rpi1+deb9u1)
valgrind version: valgrind-3.13.0
 I can't seem to locate the problem since the function Log::Book::record() get it's value via pass-by-value. I can also say that this error isn't always shown when the function is called. It is deterministic in the sense of on what line the error shows and on what line not. Can anybody direct my in direction of what this problem is and the solution for it? Code snippet below with a comment of the indicated lines.

```
/** log message */
void Book::record(std::string file, const int line, const unsigned int level, Identifier id, const std::string message,
                  const std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point timeStamp)
{
    if (!(fileLevels & level) && !(consoleLevels & level)) { return; }

    auto now = Time::keeper->now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(timeStamp - Time::globalEpoch);

    //generate message
    auto entry = std::make_unique<Entry>(level);

    // Time since startup
    addField(entry, 0, std::to_string(duration.count()));

    //UTC Time
    addField(entry, 1, now.dateTime());

    // File
    std::string stringFile;
    if (!file.empty())
    {
        stringFile = URL{file}.lastPathComponent();
    }
    addField(entry, 2, stringFile);

    //Line number
    addField(entry, 3, std::to_string(line));

    //ID
    addField(entry, 4, id);

    //Message
    std::string stringMessage;
    if(!message.empty())
    {
        addField(entry, 5, message); //this is line LogBook.cpp:87
    }
    else
    {
        addField(entry, 5, " empty message.");
    }
    *entry << ";";

    //queue message
    this->append(std::move(entry));
}
void Book::addField(std::unique_ptr<Entry> &entry, unsigned int index, const std::string &text)
{
    std::string textOutput;

    if ((spacings.at(index) != 0) && (text.length() > (spacings.at(index) - 1)))
    {
        spacings.at(index) = (uint8_t) (text.length() + 2);
    }

    entry->setWidth(spacings.at(index));

    if(entry->empty())
        textOutput = text;
    else
        textOutput = ";" + text;   //This is line LogBook.cpp:149

    if(!textOutput.empty())
        (*entry) << textOutput;
}
```

The code where this function gets called and this problem occurs.

```
auto node = child(items, "item", index);
auto enabled = boolValue(node, "enabled", false);
auto file = pathValue(node, key::path);
auto name = stringValue(node, "name", "");
auto type = stringValue(node, "type");

CLOG(CLOG::WARNING, "Yard item " + name + " not enabled, path:" + file.path());
```

---

**Update 1:**
I compile with cmake with the options. And added extra options. These didn't solve the problem.

```
add_compile_options(-ggdb)
add_compile_options(-O1)

#Extra disable vectorization
add_compile_options(-fno-tree-vectorize)
add_compile_options(-fno-tree-loop-vectorize)
add_compile_options(-fno-tree-slp-vectorize)
```

---

**Update 2:**
I've found an other place where string concatenation is used and valgrind reports te same errors

---

**Update 3:**
Some time and interesting discoveries later. 
Error happens in a shared library libarmmem.so. This gets dynamically loaded and is by this reason always on a different address. Used gdb and valgrind combination to break when the error happens.
gdb loaded shared libraries with starting address.

```
(gdb) info sharedlibrary
From        To          Syms Read   Shared Object Library
0x0483246c  0x04832750  Yes         /usr/local/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_core-arm-linux.so
0x04846e60  0x04850c10  Yes         /usr/local/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-arm-linux.so
0x04863588  0x048672fc  Yes (*)     /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so
...
```

Error reported by valgrind.

```
==9442== Invalid read of size 8
==9442==    at 0x4865D34: ??? (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libarmmem.so)
```

We know from readelf of libarmmem.so that the .text section begins on 588. and that memcpy sits on 710. The disassembly on this breakpoint shows we are in memcpy on address 0x04863710. If we check the range like : 0x04863588 - 0x04863710 = 188. 188 + 588(starting adress of .text) = 710.
Disassembly shows it happens on a assembly line. vldmia is a instruction for  Load Vector Floating Point registers.

```
0x04865d34 <+9764>: vldmia  r1!, {d9}
```

No solution yet.

Comment: Compile with `-O1` and rerun your tests. `-O2` and above produce spurious findings. Also see [The Valgrind Quick Start Guide](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/QuickStart.html).

Comment: @jww I'm already compiling with the flags -ggdb -O0 -Wextra -std=c++14. I suppose valgrind can use -ggdb.

Comment: valgrind , sadly, can't differentiate between intentional out of bounds ("legal") that happened due vectorization of operations and  and one that happened by accident. Try disable vectorization for compiler (and yes, it might be issue with newer ones in O0 mode) and see if that still happens

Comment: It happens in `textOutput = ";" + text;  ` according to output of valgrind. Call of `reserve` happens when it creates new temporary string object that must fit result of concatenation within `operator+`.  There shouldn't be issue there unless heap somehow was damaged.

Comment: *unless heap somehow was damaged* second that. In this case the root cause is not shown in the program above, as it happened earlier.

Comment: I've used following compiler options     add_compile_options(-fno-tree-vectorize)    add_compile_options(-fno-tree-loop-vectorize)   add_compile_options(-fno-tree-slp-vectorize) And check them with -Q -O0 --help=optimizers. They are disabled. @Swift-FridayPie what do you mean stack is damaged? I get dozens of these error logs, but not always when the line is called. Program keeps running. So how can i identify where the stack gets damaged?

Comment: That output does NOT mean an error happened inside `Log::Book::addField` or the string functions. It means an error happened somewhere inside libarmmem.so, but valgrind was not able to determine what functions called that library, and the error involved a pointer which is near the end of memory previously allocated by the `std::string` functions during `Log::Book::addField`.

Comment: @aschepler. Is there a way that we can make valgrind show which functions get called? So I can fix the invalid reads.

Comment: Can you share libarmmem.so? Note, that's possible that this is not a problem, as maybe the code in libarmmem.so don't over-read if the read would cross a page (usually there are suppressions for this kind of code in valgrind - maybe it's just missing).

Comment: @geza The file can be downloaded from [here](https://bjorngulf.stackstorage.com/s/kpEmZ6nrWY1HAJz). readelf doesn't give much information except that in this file the mem functions (memcpy, memset, ...) reside. I understand that valgrind uses it's own functions for memory manipulation. So why does this file gets called?

Comment: @BjornVanTilt: I've checked that file. Unfortunately, I cannot map 0x4865D1C to a point in .so file. According to the .so, .text segment need to be aligned to 0x10000. But the address 0x5d1c is not in this .so file. So I don't know what's going on. Note, that valgrind doesn't provide all memory manipulation functions. It provides memory allocation, but not memcpy, etc. Maybe if you can put a breakpoint to this address, and get a disassembly, we could find what's going on (valgrind can cooperate with gdb quite nicely, it can break gdb, when an issue is found).

Comment: Looking at those numbers, something is trying to read the end of your string buffer as if it is an array of larger objects. As others have said this is often done as an optimisation, as mallocaed memory is usually surrounded by management furniture, so the extra read is "harmless" so long as the optimisation doesn't actually use the value. Often there are a set of exclusions/annotations you can apply for the particular stdlib implementation?

Comment: @geza. I've maid an update. The address space is correct because of dynamic loading of the library.

Comment: @GemTaylor It certainly looks that way. So i'm probably going to write a ignore file for valgrind to ignore these messages. It would be nice if valgrinds knows this already and doesn't complain on it. If that is the real problem. At this point it's more of a hypothesis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probly the code inside libarmem.so has been vectorized in such a way that it realizes that there's a terminating char only after reading full 8-byte chunk. This will not trigger a processor exception (as algorithm ensures that pointer is aligned and thus stays in the same page) but will cause tools like Valgrind to report false positives.

Problems like this are getting worse over time and making Valgrind less useful in practice. See [Valgrind vs Optimising Compilers](https://archive.fosdem.org/2018/schedule/event/debugging_tools_memcheck/) for an in-depth discussion or [this bug in diff](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-diffutils/2013-08/msg00020.html) for real-world example (or [my Debian suppression list](https://github.com/yugr/debian_pkg_test/blob/master/examples/valgrind-preload/suppressions.txt) for even more examples).